# Impossible to change subnet in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, static-ip

I need a little help, I had setup a VPN server on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 (with GUI) (Actually, I’m using Ubuntu Desktop as server) and to avoid conflicts with the default gateways of other routers outside my network when I connect to the VPN, I decided to switch my subnet from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.77.0/24.

So… here comes the problem, my server is a HP ProLiant MicroServer G8 and it comes with three network interfaces, one to manage the server even if it’s powered off (HP iLO) and two regular ones, in ubuntu they show up as “eno1” and “eno2” respectively.

The day that I configured the static IP I went for the GUI mode in the interface eno1, so I changed it in the configuration app of Ubuntu, I didn’t use netplan or anything else.
Today, when I had to change it from 192.168.1.77 to 192.168.77.77 Ubuntu wouldn’t grab it no matter what I do. When I managed to get the IP in the interface the gateway will continue to stay as 192.168.1.1, and after doing several troubleshooting steps I had it working if I manually remove the gateway from the route table and add the new one with a command, the problem is when I reboot the server it will lose the route and put back again the 192.168.1.1 one.

After a lot of hours spent, I opt to connect the network cable to the other interface (eno2) and remove the reservation of the IP with the MAC in the router. I configured the static IP and it starts working at the moment.
My question here is, why is this happening? Thanks

PS: Sorry for my bad English, I am not native.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from this vague description. Please be specific about what you did. Include the exact changes you made to every file.

Comment: Probably [DHCP lease time](https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/what-is-dhcp-lease-time-and-how-to-change-it/) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It was the dhcp server (/etc/dhcpcd.conf), even thought I never used it, it had the static IP assigned for the interface, so changing it fixed the problem. Thanks